# XCode Debugging / Tracing Zombies / Leaks in Instruments

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments, memory-leaks, zombie-process

Before I updated Xcode I used to be able to double click a zombie/leak in Instruments and it would take me directly to the instigating code, but now I cannot seem to do that and I dont know why, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do Zombies in Simulator, not on the device.

You can do other stuff with the device (like Allocations and Leaks, but Zombies is meant to only work with the Simulator).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to open the Extended Detail pane (the one on the right). In it, you can double-click your culprit method to show it in Xcode.

Reference: [Instruments User Guide: Eradicating Zombies with the Zombies Trace Template](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW8).